# Use reflection to get app.dispatcher from class library

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way to get the app dispatcher from a class library using reflection? Nothing I've tried has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the dispatcher by calling `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher`

You need to add references to `PresentationFramework`, `WindowsBase`, `System.Xaml` to access `Application` class from ordinary class library.

Comment: Yes, that I know.  But you can't call that from a class library - only from an application project.